# Add class 'active' in AJAX Pagination issue

Tags: jquery, ajax, pagination

I'm trying to add active class when I click on page number, but the class disappear when ajax call load the page.

I tried many ways to fix it, but I couldn't since

How can I fix this problem ?

```
 function loadData(page)
        {
            $('.loading-info').show();
            if (typeof page === 'undefined') {
                page = ''
            } else{
                page = '&page='+page
            }
            $.ajax
            ({
                type: "POST",
                url: "../inc/ajax/ajax_view/user_assgined_view_hi.php",
                data: "page="+page,
                success: function(msg)
                {
                    $("#results").html(msg);
                    $('.loading-info').hide();

                }
            });
        }


            $(document).on('click','.paging',function(e){
            var page = ($(this).attr("id"));
            loadData(page);
                if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
                    $(this).removeClass('active');
                } else {
                    $(this).addClass('active');
                }
        });
```

Comment: You should show your html as well

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead!

```
$(".paging").on("click", function(){
    var page = $(this).attr("id");
    $('.loading-info').show();

    if (typeof page === 'undefined') {
        page = '';
    } else {
        page = '&page=' + page
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../inc/ajax/ajax_view/user_assgined_view_hi.php",
        data: "page=" + page,
        success: function(msg){
            $("#results").html(msg);
            $('.loading-info').hide();
        }
    });

    $(this).toggleClass("active");
});
```

Comment: didn't work either,  the active disappear after calling   loadData(page);

Comment: @user3763103 give me one moment

Comment: @user3763103 try now :-)

Comment: Thank you, but  the problem persists .  calling  loadData(page); it's kinda reloading the page mmm

Comment: @user3763103 I have removed the need to call `loadData();`

Comment: wait, can you please display your html